# Elastic Search: How to search an index which matches a field value from another index field

Tags: elasticsearch, subquery, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation, opensearch

I have two indices " index01 " and " index02 " with the following feilds

#### index01

- department
- name
- salary

#### index02

- course_name
- course_id

I have to make a single query to fetch the documents from index01 where the department matches with the course_name. can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an enrichment policy.
The first index will be the main index and the second index will be the lookup index.

Another example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75520387/10685211

[Example: Enrich your data based on exact values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/match-enrich-policy-type.html)

[image]